# where the inner class be placed is right in java

Tags: java

where the inner class be placed is right in java?
at the beginning of the outer class, or between the outer class fields declared position with outer class constructor or at the end of end class or first use place?
any rule or best pratice?

Comment: There is no "right place."  Wherever you think reads best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [The Java Coding Style Guide](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/products/archive/whitepapers/java-style.pdf). Particularly section 6.1 describes the suggested layout for a class.

Comment: if there are too inner static inner class, how to assign their order? such as subclass extends parentclass, there are both inner class, which is first? if assign them according to call sequence, the subclass is first, if assign them according to read sequence, the parent class is first, so which is first better?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the document that I linked which has any suggestions. I'd just choose one or the other and stick with it consistently throughout a project.

Comment: I don't seee anywhere too. As you mentioned, keep some stycl is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

An inner class is typically placed at the end of the outer class in Java before the last closing brace of the outer class.

In my opinion, this is better than placing them at the beginning for readability purposes - people usually wish to determine the context of 
the outer class *first* before looking at the inner class(es).

Comment: if there are too inner static inner class, how to assign their order? such as subclass extends parentclass, there are both inner class, which is first? if assign them according to call sequence, the subclass is first, if assign them according to read sequence, the parent class is first, so which is first better?

Answer (score 2):

Once I read [“coding style” for GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/makinggwtbetter#codestyle) where advice to put nested types (inner and static classes) at the top of the class declaration before all other elements. After this I always do this in such way because this makes your class code more readable.

Comment: if there are too inner static inner class, how to assign their order? such as subclass extends parentclass, there are both inner class, which is first? if assign them according to call sequence, the subclass is first, if assign them according to read sequence, the parent class is first, so which is first better?